# My Greenfoot Program works as a greenfoot file but not a jar file

Tags: java, greenfoot

I am making a little arcade full of Vocabulary Games for school. When I run the program in the greenfoot window, it runs perfectly. But when I make a jar file of it, it stops when it is Prompted with Greenfoot.ask(). Here's the code:

```
import greenfoot.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Vocabulary 
{
   static ArrayList<World> back = new ArrayList<World>();
   static String vocab_List;
   static Scanner list =  null;
   static ArrayList<String> last = new ArrayList<String>();
   static Scanner all;
   static ArrayList<String> problems = new ArrayList<String>();
   static Map<String, String> answers = new HashMap<String, String>();
   static int x2 = 0;
   static int y = 1;
   static int count= 0;
   static boolean an;
   static World help;
   static int right = 0;

   public static boolean run() throws IOException
   {      
       right = 0;
       Collections.shuffle(problems);
      for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
      {
         String[] def = answers.get(problems.get(x)).split(" ");
         String answer = Greenfoot.ask("What does " + problems.get(x) + " mean?");
         count = 0;
         for(String temp: def)
         {
            if(answer.contains(temp))
               count++;
         }
         if(count > def.length/2 && count > 1 || count == def.length)
         {
            help.showText("Correct",300,100);
            Greenfoot.delay(50);
            right++;
         }
         else
         {
            help.showText("Actually... it means " + answers.get(problems.get(x)), 300, 100);
            Greenfoot.delay(50);
         }
         if(right >= 2)
         {
            an = true;
         }
         else
         {
             an = false;
         }
         try 
            {
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
         } 
         catch (InterruptedException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }      
         help.showText("",300,100);
      }
      return an;
   }

   public static boolean run(int num) throws IOException
   {      
      right = 0;
      Collections.shuffle(problems);
      for(int x = 0; x < num; x++)
      {
         String[] def = answers.get(problems.get(x)).split(" ");
         String answer = Greenfoot.ask("What does " + problems.get(x) + " mean?");
         count = 0;
         for(String temp: def)
         {
            if(answer.contains(temp))
               count++;
         }
         if(count > def.length/2 && count > 1 || count == def.length)
         {
            help.showText("Correct",300,100);
            Greenfoot.delay(50);
            right++;
         }
         else
         {
            help.showText("Actually... it means " + answers.get(problems.get(x)), 300, 100);
            Greenfoot.delay(50);
         }
         if(right >= num/2)
         {
            an = true;
         }
         else
         {
             an = false;
         }
         try 
            {
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
         } 
         catch (InterruptedException e) 
         {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }      
         help.showText("",300,200);
      }
      return an;
   }

   public static void setBack(World world)
   {
       back.add(world);
   }
   public static void setMode(ArrayList<Integer> lesson) throws IOException
   {
       problems.clear();
       answers.clear();
       x2 = 0;
       all = new Scanner(new File("All_Vocab.in"));
       for(int x : lesson)
       {
           list = new Scanner(new File("Vocab " + x + ".in"));
         while(all.hasNextLine())
         {
            last.add(all.nextLine() + "\n");
         }
         FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("All_Vocab.in");
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
         for(int c = 0; c < last.size(); c++)
         {
            bw.write(last.get(c));
         }
         bw.write(vocab_List+".in");
         bw.close();
         while(list.hasNextLine())
         {
             problems.add(list.nextLine());
             answers.put(problems.get(x2), list.nextLine());
             x2++;
         }
       }

   }

   public static void setHelp(World hell)
   {
       help = hell;
    }
}
```

If you need the whole project, just tell me and I'll share it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the problem was that the scanner wasn't reading the file because it couldn't find the pathway in the jar.It pauses at Greenfoot.ask because when reading the files, it threw  an IOException, making the file continue, eventually causing a NullPointerException